# Error: Request is not available in this context

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I have this code in global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
       // Code that runs on application startup  
        if (Request.Cookies["mylang"] == null)  
        {  
            HttpCookie mylang = new HttpCookie("mylang");  
            mylang.Value = "fa";
            mylang.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(mylang);
            Session.Add("mylang", "fa");
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Request.Cookies["mylang"].Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Request.Cookies["mylang"].Value);
        Session["mylang"] = Request.Cookies["mylang"].Value;
    }
```

But when I run my website below error was shown:

> Request is not available in this context

Why?

Comment: You're not in a request yet?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I didn't understand your question

Comment: Sorry, I meant to make that a statement. You are not in the middle of a request while you're in Application_Start.

Answer (score 1):

**Application_Start** is called once before any ASP files are processed. That is why **Request** is not available yet.

You want to use **Application_BeginRequest** which is called on each request.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Config.Init();

   // Code that runs on application startup
   if (Request.Cookies["mylang"] == null)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

[Application_Start vs Application_BeginRequest event in Global.aspx](http://www.codeease.com/application_start-vs-application_beginrequest-event-in-global-aspx.html)